# c++ Unordered List Example

Tags: c++, list, unordered

I realized that c++ list is ordering the entries. Do you know whether there is an unordered list defined in C++? Is there any example?

Thanks

Comment: c++ list is unordered, it has no comparison of values. do you mean a different data structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I realized that c++ list is ordering the entries.

This is actually not true.

[`std::list`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/forward_list/forward_list/) does not perform any type of ordering, other than preserving the order you specify as you add items.

Note that `std::vector` also does not reorder, and is more appropriate in many cases if you just need a collection of values which can be stored and retrieved as necessary.